# IClaimsTransformation not firing

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-3.1

I've tried to implement an `IClaimsTransformation` class I found in my ASP.NET CORE 3.1 web app

```
public class ClaimsTransformer : IClaimsTransformation
{
    public ClaimsTransformer(IHttpContextAccessor httpAccessor) { }

    public Task<ClaimsPrincipal> TransformAsync(ClaimsPrincipal p)
    {
        p.AddIdentity(new ClaimsIdentity());
        return Task.FromResult(p);
    }
}
```

And I've added it like so:

```
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {

        services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
            options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("MyConString")));

        services.AddAuthentication(IISDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);

        services.AddSingleton<IClaimsTransformation, ClaimsTransformer>();

        services.AddIdentity<IdentityUser, IdentityRole>()
            .AddRoleManager<RoleManager<IdentityRole>>()
            .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()
            .AddDefaultTokenProviders();

        ...
```

And while the constructor gets hit during startup, the `TransformAsync()` method never fires when visitng a controller. What am I missing? There are several implementations adding `IClaimsTransformation` but none of them have any more info other than the class and adding via singleton / transient

Although I should add I've seen various examples of `app.UseClaimsTransformation()` but that's not available in 3.1

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you're having the same issue, which has been solved [here](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/18040#issuecomment-570629578)

> AddAuthentication sets the DefaultScheme (Windows), but AddIdentity sets the DefaultAuthenticateScheme (Identity.Application) which takes priority for the Auth middleware. You're not logged in using Identity cookies so claims transformation doesn't run. Commenting out AddIdentity gets you back to Windows auth and allows transformations to run. Setting DefaultAuthenticateScheme to IISDefaults.AuthenticationScheme after AddIdentity also fixes it.

Comment: I tried rearranging the order of the `services` additions but it didn't work, and I can't comment out `AddIdentity` because I need it (but actually if I do comment it out to test, I get an error on my `ClaimsTransformer` but at least it's being hit then...) I don't know why rearranging the order doesn't work.