# IClaimsTransformation not being called

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-identity

I am developing an ASP.NET Core Web app (.NET 5.0).
This is an intranet app, so I am using Windows Authentication.
For Authorization, I am using custom roles from AspNetCore.Identity (don't want to use AD groups for various reasons).
I am using the `IClaimsTransformation` class to implement a `TransformAsync` method in order to add my custom roles to the user's claim.
I added the `[Authorize(Roles = "Admin")]` on a controller to test the whole scheme.

When I test in Debug (IIS Express), the `TransformAsync` method never gets called.

I did check that Windows Authentication is enabled for IIS in my `launchSettings.json`:

```
  "iisSettings": {
    "windowsAuthentication": true,
    "anonymousAuthentication": false,
    "iisExpress": {
      "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:49861",
      "sslPort": 44307
    }
```

I also checked that windowsAuthentication is enabled for Debug mode (IIS Express):
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XP3hX.png)

Below is my `ConfigureServices` method (`startup.cs`) :

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>
                (options => options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
            
            services.AddControllersWithViews();

            // Windows Authentication
            services.AddAuthentication(IISDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);

            // Claim transformation
            services.AddScoped<IClaimsTransformation, AddRolesClaimsTransformation>();

            //ASP Identity
            services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>().AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();

        }
```

and this is my `Configure` method (`startup.cs`) :

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
                app.UseHsts();
            }
            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseStaticFiles();

            app.UseRouting();
            app.UseAuthentication();
            app.UseAuthorization();

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    pattern: "{controller=Event}/{action=Dashboard}/{id?}");
            });
        }
```

and this is the `TransformAsync` method :

```
public class AddRolesClaimsTransformation : IClaimsTransformation
    {
        private readonly UserManager<ApplicationUser> _userManager;

        public AddRolesClaimsTransformation(UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager)
        {
            _userManager = userManager;
        }

        public async Task<ClaimsPrincipal> TransformAsync(ClaimsPrincipal principal)
        {
            //code removed for simplicity - this never gets called 
        }
  }
```

I tried changing the order `services.AddAuthentication(IISDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)` in `startup.cs` as suggested in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65167381/iclaimstransformation-not-firing) but this did not solve the problem.

What am I missing ?

Comment: You can refer to the [link](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/18040),and check what `Tratcher` said `Your app has both Identity and Windows Auth enabled, and Identity is winning.`

Comment: Thanks for the comment - I actually came across that thread before submitting my question here and attempted the suggestion (calling  services.AddIdentity first then  services.addAuthentication ) but this did not resolve the issue. I just came across this doc from Microsoft ([ink](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/windowsauth?view=aspnetcore-5.0&tabs=visual-studio) ):  When hosting with IIS, AuthenticateAsync isn't called internally to initialize a user. Therefore, an IClaimsTransformation implementation (..) isn't activated by default.

Comment: Full doc from Microsoft: "When hosting with IIS, AuthenticateAsync isn't called internally to initialize a user. Therefore, an IClaimsTransformation implementation used to transform claims after every authentication isn't activated by default. For more information and a code example that activates claims transformations, see ASP.NET Core Module (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/aspnet-core-module?view=aspnetcore-5.0#in-process-hosting-model)." I could not find the code example mentioned above - if you can let me know !

Comment: Found the "code example(https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/aspnet-core-module?view=aspnetcore-3.0#in-process-hosting-model)" mentioned in my comment above (needed to switch from Core 5.0 to Core 3.0 in the doc). The suggestion is to add `services.AddAuthentication(IISServerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)` which I already have.

Answer (score 7):

I finally found a solution to my own question.
The solution was to change the call to `services.AddAuthentication()` in `ConfigureServices` method (`startup.cs`) as follows:

BEFORE:

```
services.AddAuthentication(IISDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
```

AFTER:

```
services.AddAuthentication(options =>
            {
                options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = IISDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            });
```

This is the full code for `ConfigureServices` method (`startup.cs`):

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>
                (options => options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
            
    services.AddControllersWithViews();

    //ASP Identity
    services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole> 
    ().AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();

    // Claim transformation
    services.AddScoped<IClaimsTransformation, AddRolesClaimsTransformation>();

    // Windows Authentication
    services.AddAuthentication(options =>
     {
       options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme =  IISDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
     });
}
```

Comment: How did you figure this out?

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an older thread. I had the same issue. What I noticed was that, when the calling client did not specify any scopes to my API, the IClaimsTransformer was not being called. I added in a policy to my service to require at least a default scope to be declared and it now works as expected.

```
services.AddAuthorization(options => {
            List<string> requiredScopes = Configuration.GetSection("RequiredScopes")?.GetChildren().Select(x => x.Value).ToList();
            var policy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder()
                .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
                .RequireScope(requiredScopes)
                .Build();
            options.AddPolicy("Security Requirements", policy);
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

Whene you use identity you must be add this lines after the identity in services

```
services.AddAuthentication(opt => {
    opt.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = IISDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    opt.DefaultChallengeScheme = IISDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
});
```

because The Identity is used its own authentication

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>
                (options => options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
            
            services.AddControllersWithViews();

            // Claim transformation
            services.AddScoped<IClaimsTransformation, AddRolesClaimsTransformation>();

            //ASP Identity
            services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>().AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();
            services.AddAuthentication(opt => {
                opt.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = IISDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                opt.DefaultChallengeScheme = IISDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            });

        }
```